# What does the error message "com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: The database URL cannot be null." mean?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with MySQL Database. If I run my code, a `WrongArgumentException` saying that the `databaseURL cannot be null`.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/reserving?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

##Mapper Config##
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.springboot.reserving
mybatis.mapper-locations=mapper/**/*.xml

spring.devtools.livereload.enabled =true

spring.freemarker.cache=false
```

Error message:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class
 because of underlying exception: 
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: The database URL cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change property `spring.datasource.jdbc-url` to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/reserving?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property named `spring.datasource.jdbc-url` in [application-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Change

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url
```

To

```
spring.datasource.url
```

---

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/reserving?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```